# Jquery select2 : How to trigger unselect event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to trigger unselect event on select2 select box

```
$("select.js-example-basic-multiple").trigger({
    type:'select2:unselect',
    params:{
        data:e
    }
});
```

The Event Handler is this

```
$('body').find('.js-example-basic-multiple').on("select2:unselect", function (e) {  
     var data = e.params.data;
     $('body').find('select.js-example-basic-multiple option:contains("'+data.element.text+'")').prop("disabled",false).end().find('select.js-example-basic-multiple').select2('destroy').select2();
});
```

In the event handler, I am using e.params.data.element.text, this is a default.

when I trigger the event I don't know what to pass as data.

I tried

```
e = {
        'params':{
            'data':{
                'element':{
                    'text':$text
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Here text is the selected options text value

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined in the
>   event handler

**STORY**

Initally I have only one select2 select box. If the user clicks add new button I am  destroying the select2 on the first select2 select box and clone and append and apply the select2 again on both the select boxes..  This happens everytime the user clicks add new button.

A option selected in one select2 box should not be selected on other select2 select boxes. 
And a option deselected in one select2 select box, can be selected in any one of the other select2 select boxes.

I am updating the select boxes every time the select and unselect events are triggered.

For example :
When unselect event is triggered. when the selected option is deselected manually.

```
 $('body').find('.js-example-basic-multiple').on("select2:unselect", function (e) {  
      var data = e.params.data;
      $('body').find('select.js-example-basic-multiple option:contains("'+data.element.text+'")').prop("disabled",false).end().find('select.js-example-basic-multiple').select2('destroy').select2();
 });
```

My problem is newly created select2 select boxes have remove button. This remove button removes the whole select box, at this time I need to update all the other select2 select boxes. problem is this doesn't trigger any events. we need to change it manually..

Comment: It would probably be much easier to just deselect the `option` element, then trigger a `change()` event on the `select`. Select2 should then pick up the change itself

Comment: @Rory McCrossan bro I have updated my question with story section. please read it.